# Linux on reboot process with PPID 1 do not clean up resources (socket)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, process, network-programming

Upon system reboot linux my networking application demon with ppid 1 is not tearing down the socket connections.
However it tears down the connection if kill that demon using kill -9 manually.

I also notice same behavior if I run a application with nohup. On reboot it is not tearing down connection, where as it tear downs when nohup is not used.

Please provide pointers how to handle proper cleanup resources for demons.

Comment: Do you have some script or whatever that signals those processes when you reboot? Why do you expect those processes to terminate connections otherwise?

Comment: Signal 9 cannot be caught.  A process receiving that signal will be terminated by the kernel immediately, without any shutdown hooks being called.  If that's in fact the behavior you want, then your claim that it does not happen when the system reboots (and you have no provision for a cleaner shutdown) is simply not credible.

Comment: When my process terminates there should be proper handshake in tcp layer FIN FIN-ACK to happen for proper tcp closure. This is not happening, and hence other end netstat shows connection ESTABLISHED, although system got rebooted. There seems some difference in way linux terminates process with PPID 1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. I did not implement procedure to properly close open sockets. But I see proper closure for normal application whose  parent is bash shell on reboot. But if i run same application with nohup or during starup then PPID will be 1. In such case OS is not automatically cleaning up sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume any cleanup whatever in the event that your server process is sent a `KILL` signal (i.e. signal 9).  It is usual, however, for a service to provide some means to trigger a clean shutdown.  That could be in the form of an appropriate handler for the `TERM` signal (signal 15), which is desirable to have in any case.

Moreover, it is wise to set up your service to be managed via your system's service-management subsystem, whether that's SystemV-style init scripts, systemd, or any of the myriad other alternatives.  That way you have a lot more control over how and *when* the system shuts down your service during a system reboot or shutdown, plus it's easier to manage your service manually when that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.

TCP active close requires sending `FIN` and waiting for `FIN/ACK`. Obviously, when the system is asked to reboot it should not wait for `FIN/ACK`. It could still send that `FIN` or `RST` though.

However, your other application must not expect the peer to send `FIN` or `RST` on connection failure. If you unplug the ethernet cable from the machine, for example, and your application does not send any data, it will never be notified that the peer has disconnected. Instead, your application should send keep-alive messages to detect a broken connection.